# HDRI rendering onto parts of a model

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri

[image]Hello everyone and thanks in advance. The resource of already answered questions has really helped me to learn blender after 17 years in Vectorworks.

This is a weird one and I've seen it twice now. Once on geometry I build and now on an imported model. the HDRI is actually rendering ONTO parts of the model and nothing I do seems to change this. Deleting the HDRI leaves an untextured surface and this surface will not take a texture at all despite one being applied.

Note that:
It looks fine in texture mode
Yes, it's unwrapped
I've tried replicating the texture, changes nothing but I can see that the original texture shows pink in the texture dialogue indicating that it thinks something is missing.
Another thing to note in the last two screenshots:
When I select a normally textured object you can see in the path there is object and then material but if I click on the wrongly textured object it just shows the material. somehow the object itself is not in the path.

Here is an extrude with the problem (coloured) set into a new file with a simple cube and plane and a random HDRI background. You can see that the problem object is basically invisible.
[image][image]
[image][image]

BTW is 
Help! :)
Adam

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the texture being reflected on the surface? Can you show the node tree for the material you are having issues with?

Comment: Not a reflection, actually rendered to the surface. Yes I can show the node tree. Give me ten.

Comment: I'm sure it's not in the node tree.

Comment: Afteer doing that last test I can see that light from the object is reflecting onto the cube, suggesting the object is set to a mode other than solid...

Comment: Can you upload the blend file with the 3 objects and hdri? There could be a number of things going on that would be easier to solve if we can see the file.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to find the issue. See below :)

Answer (score -3):

The object was set as *Shadow Catcher* in Cycles settings.

Disabling that solved the problem.